# Visual Studio extension: How do I find which tool window is in the foreground in a tab link group?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsx

In Visual Studio, you can group tool windows together and identify them by their tabs. For example, you might have the "Output", "Error List", and "Find Results 1" tool windows grouped together in a panel below your document. When you click on the "Output" tab, it comes to the foreground and grabs focus. If you click back to the document window, the "Output" tab is still on top (in the foreground).

How can I programmatically (in a VS extension) determine (1) which windows are in the same tab group, and (2) which window is in the foreground, when given one of the windows in a group?

Here's a code sample enumerating all windows:

```
    var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
    var windowOutput = dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput);
    foreach (EnvDTE.Window w in windowOutput.LinkedWindowFrame.Collection)
    {
        //gives every window, not just those grouped together
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to save/restore a subset of the layout in memory, fast, which will then be assigned to a keyboard shortcut. I know there are add-ins which do this, but they're slow.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. There seems to be an example on manipulating linked window frames [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h41w1yxb(v=vs.120).aspx); not sure how accurate/useful it is.

Comment: @Cameron, that's close, it shows how to create a linked window frame, but not how to find existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out when a tab is switched to by initially iterating through all the EnvDTE windows (`Window`/`Window2`), getting the corresponding `IVsWindowFrame`s, and subscribing for frame notifications (`IVsWindowFrameNotify`) so that you get notified when a tab changes. But this still won't help with tab groups ("linked frames"), not to mention the headache of keeping your window frame listeners up to date (when tabs open/close, etc.).

The only reliable thing I can think of is to export the settings to XML (VS does this to preserve the layout from run to run), manipulate the XML, then later import it. I'm not sure how fast this would be though, but it's worth a try. You can search for `Environment_WindowLayout` in your .vssettings file to see an example of the XML. Actually doing an  export/import of this info is tricky -- you can try your luck with the `EnvDTE.Properties` collection, and perhaps the IVsUIShellDocumentWindowMgr ([example](https://github.com/shanselman/RestoreAfterReloadVSIX/blob/master/ReloadPackagePackage.cs)) would come in handy, but perhaps not.

Comment: Yes, [Layouts O Rama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c) uses the vssetings technique. It takes over a second though, and I'm trying to be almost instant. I'd rather know exactly how a vssettings import/export works - is it using a publically available API?

Comment: @Jon: I looked for an API, but couldn't find one beyond `EnvDTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings" ...)` ([example](https://github.com/lennybacon/VSScreenProfiles/blob/master/src/VSScreenSizeProfiles/ScreenProfilesPackage.cs)). `IVsProfileDataManager` looked promising at first glance but doesn't seem to expose any actual settings values.

Comment: @Jon: Finally, [this](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VsVimShared/Extensions.cs#L584) looks promising. If nothing else, you can iterate through all the frames and figure out the tab groups by looking at who shares the same parents. Redocking might be tricky though.

Comment: @Jon: Aha! You can get an instance of the `IVsWindowFrameManager` service and call `ExportSettings` on it, then later `ImportSettings`. It's all done in-memory, and for export you only have to implement `WriteSettingXmlFromString()`.

Comment: I tried your link above but TryGetParent returns null. I couldn't find IVsWindowFrameManager/ExportSetting references, did you mean IVsWindowFrame? +1 as I think this is close (although still not sure how fast it'd be).

Comment: @Jon: I imagine TryGetParent only works for non-root windows? Not sure why it would return null. Anyway, I meant `IVsWindowManager`, sorry! It has `ImportSettings` and `ExportSettings` methods. If you decompile the implementation of ExportSettings, it merely writes an XML document in memory, which should be quite fast (though it first gets the window profiles, I suppose that could be slow internally).

Comment: Also, I can see the info in a watch window for EnvDTE.Window -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase -> ContextAttributes -> Parent -> DockViewElement -> IsOnScreen. The problem is, some of those members are private.

Comment: No luck getting IVsWindowManager to work - not sure what assembly or namespace it's in. None of the entries here worked: http://whatdll.com/type/IVsWindowManager.html

Comment: @Jon: OK, I guess they're technically internal interfaces, but they're declared public -- `IVsWindowManager`/`IVsWindowManager2`/`IVsWindowManager3` are in the `Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop` namespace, in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement assembly.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't see that namespace in that assembly (Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll)

Comment: @Jon: Hmm, odd. I just double checked, and those three interfaces (and their containing namespace) are there for me. Same DLL path here (though normally I look at the one from the GAC, but they're the same, I checked). What decompiler are you using? I see them with both JustDecompile and dotPeek.